# AWK: Print lines matching a pattern

Tags: awk

I have a tab separated file where the last fifteen fields are formed of zeros and ones. What it's need to do is print lines that do not contain more than five consecutive zeros or more than five consecutive ones, between those fifteen fields separated by groups of five fields.

File:

```
abadenguísimo   abadenguísimo   adjective   n/a n/a singular    n/a masculine   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
abalaustradísimo    abalaustradísimo    adjective   n/a n/a singular    n/a masculine   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
abiertísimas    abiertísimo adjective   n/a n/a plural  n/a feminine    1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
abellacadísimo  abellacadísimo  adjective   n/a n/a singular    n/a masculine   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
cansonísimos    cansonísimo adjective   n/a n/a plural  n/a masculine   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Output:

```
abellacadísimo  abellacadísimo  adjective   n/a n/a singular    n/a masculine   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
cansonísimos    cansonísimo adjective   n/a n/a plural  n/a masculine   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

I tried this:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t"

    }
    {
    a=0;
    b=0;
    c=0;

    num[A]="";
    num[B]="";
    num[C]="";


        for ( i = 9; i <= 13; i++)
            num[A]=num[A]""$i;
        for (j = 14; j <= 18; j++)
            num[B]=num[B]""$j;
        for (k = 19; k <= 23; k++)
            num[C]=num[C]""$k;



    if ((num[A] != "00000") && (num[A] != "11111")) {
        a=1;
    }
    if (num[B] != "00000") {
        b=1;
    }
    if (num[C] != "00000") {
        c=1;
    }
    if ((a == 1) || (b == 1) || (c == 1)) {
        print;
    }
    }
```

Finally I think I've found a solution, I don't know why the other code doesn't work for me.

```
BEGIN {
FS = "\t"
cont=0;
}

{
a=0;
b=0;
c=0;

sum1=$9+$10+$11+$12+$13;
sum2=$14+$15+$16+$17+$18;
sum3=$19+$20+$21+$22+$23;

if (( sum1 > 0 ) && ( sum1 < 5 )) {
a=1;
}
if ( sum2 > 0 ) {
b=1;
}
if ( sum3 > 0 ) {
c=1;
}

if ((a == 1) || (b == 1) || (c == 1)) {

cont++;
print;
}

}

END {
print "Total: "NR;
print "OK: "cont; 
}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your code correctly, the three groups of five *are important*?  So you would *not* want to print a line with `00000 11111 00000`, but you WOULD want to print a line with `00011 11100 01010`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @ghoti yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you translate your requirement from english into regex then give to grep, it will do what you want:

```
grep -vE '(1\s+){6,}|(0\s+){6,}' file
```

You can adjust the `\s+`, for example change it to `\t` or something else for your needs.

### Update

```
awk -F'\t' '{s=NF-15+1
            c=i=0
            while(++c<=3){
                    x=i?i:s 
                    t=0
                    for(i=x;i<x+5;i++) t+=$i+0
                    if(t==0||t==5) next
            }
            print
    }' file
```

This give your the expected output. It checks the "more than **FOUR** consecutive zeros/ones" instead of **FIVE**, because each group has max. 5 elements/columns, ">5" will never happen.

Comment: If you divide the last fifteen fields into three, each of these groups can't have more than five ones or more than five zeros. Thank you.

Comment: @Criatos oh you just want to check each "group" in the last 15 fields? E.g. in this way (5 cols)(5 cols)(5 cols)?

Comment: that it's what i want

Comment: That's why including code in the question is important. :-)

Comment: @Criatos if you divide 15 cols into 3 groups, how come one group that having `more than five consecutive zeros or more than five consecutive ones`? there are totally 5 fields in each group.

Comment: @Criatos I copied your input text, and replace spaces into tab, I got desired output.

Comment: @Kent, perhaps if you explained a bit more *why* your code works, Criatos could adapt the concepts more easily to his actual data.

Answer (score 0):

awk 4

```
awk 'split($0,t,/(1 +){6,}|(0 +){6,}/)<2' file
```

awk 3.1

```
awk --posix 'split($0,t,/(1 +){6,}|(0 +){6,}/)<2' file
```

update

```
awk '{for(i=9;i<=NF;i++){a[$i];if(++c==5){l=length(a);delete a;c=0;if(l>1){print;break}}}}' file
```

Comment: If you divide the last fifteen fields into three, each of these groups can't have more than five ones or more than five zeros. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following ERE in grep works with your input data, where ALL THREE groups of five have matching content:

```
egrep -v '(\s+[01])\1\1\1\1(\s+[01])\2\2\2\2(\s+[01])\3\3\3\3' file
```

Since your question is tagged [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), though, let's express this in awk.

We can't do the same thing in awk, because awk traditionally does not support backreferences in regular expressions. So as your script suggests, doing this programmatically may be the answer. Your solution concatenates fields and compares strings. I think I would probably use arithmetic instead -- a sum of the five fields is a number from zero to five. A value of zero or five means "skip", anything else means "print".

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{

  # Count back from the end in groups of five, until we hit e field
  # that is neither "0" nor "1"...
  start=NF;
  while ($start ~ /^[01]$/) {
    group++;
    for(i=start;i>start-5;i--) { sum[group]+=$i; }
    start=i;
  }

  # Step through groups, adding a condition to a counter.
  # At the end of the loop, if found > 0, then we've found a line
  # that does not have the pattern specified.
  found=0;
  while (--group) {
    found+=(sum[group] > 1 && sum[group] < 5);
  }

}

# If found > 0, print the line.
found
```